# md5 vectorized sse* && avx

Tags: c++, c, md5, sse2, avx

I am looking for information on the implementation of md5 algorithm using vectorization.
I am interested in the details of SSE* and the AVX instructions.Are there any ready-made library with support for vectorization?

Comment: The first question you should ask yourself is why do you need MD5 anymore?

Comment: I write a brute force and I want to use all the CPU. Also, the practice of working with SIMD extensions

Comment: OK, just wanted to warn not to use it for any applications. But cracking it is ok :)

Comment: Muh sweeping binary generalizations! MD5 is a fine fast hash for many things, its weakness is when storing hashed passwords or using it alone to confirm that a file hasn't been maliciously altered. But there are many other uses for hashing things, and speed or output length may be more important than preventing collisions. eg for a hashmap data structure(speed), or digesting a passphrase into an encryption key (The key is not stored so can't be used to get the passphrase, and the only reason to have the passphrase is to get the key.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try looking at [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/), they used to have highly optimized implementations of various cryptographic algorithms used to hash passwords.